# Rails engine extending views, not overriding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I am aware that I can override an applications view from within an engine by simply creating the same file within the engine and removing it from the application (eg: 'users/show.html.erb').

However, what I want is to be able to extend the applications view, not override.

Lets say I have a `yield` inside 'users/show.html.erb' of the main application:

`yield :foo`

What I want is for the engine to specify the same file 'users/show.html.erb' and to have a `content_for` block

`content_for :foo {}`

Thereby, injecting some template data from the engines view, into the applications view.

Obviously, the above won't work as once it has found the template file in the application, it won't look for one in the engine.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to extend views that way in Rails. You can however, accomplish this by using partials. In your engine, write a partial view file `users/_show.html.erb` and then render it in your app's view:

```
# app/views/users/show

# will look for a partial called "_show.html.erb" in the engine's and app's view paths.
render partial: 'show'
```

It's just as easy as your suggestion.

This gem tries to implement partial extension of views, but it works similarly to what I just described: https://github.com/amatsuda/motorhead#partially-extending-views-in-the-main-app

Comment: Yeh, that's what I ended up going for. My solution looks for a specific partial in each engine (namespaced with the name of the engine).